# How to AutoCreate Kafka Topic according to incoming topic pattern through kafkalistener service in springboot Kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I will subscribe to kafka topic pattern such as "topic.*" My goal here to create deadletter queue for each kafka topic I listen.

For example when I listen topic named "topic.1" I would like to autocreate deadletter queue named "topic.1_deadletter" automaticly.

What I tried to do so far is like below:

My consumer:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LibraryEventsConsumer {

    @Autowired
    LibraryEventConsumerConfig libraryEventConsumerConfig;

    @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "kafka.*")
    public void onMessage(String consumerRecord, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) throws Exception{

        log.info("ConsumerRecord : {}", consumerRecord);

        String deadlettertopic = String.format("%s_deadletter",topic);
        System.out.println(deadlettertopic);
        System.out.println(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC);

        libraryEventConsumerConfig.getTopic(topic);`
```

Here with the method getTopic I am trying to autocreate kafka topic. And below you can see libraryEventConsumer class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class LibraryEventConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public void getTopic(String topic){
        NewTopic deadlettertopic = TopicBuilder.name(String.format("%s_deadletter",topic))
                .partitions(1)
                .replicas(1)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that approach did not work and I got below error message:

```
Parameter 0 of method getTopic in com.kafkalibrary.Config.LibraryEventConsumerConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

Any idea how to proceed on that?

**Solution Example Code:**

For those who are looking for same goal, here is my example code: Thanks to Gary Russell for inspiration.

```
   private static void createTopic(String topicName, int numPartitions) throws Exception {
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:5052,localhost:5053,localhost:5054");
    AdminClient admin = AdminClient.create(config);

    //checking if topic already exists
    boolean alreadyExists = admin.listTopics().names().get().stream()
            .anyMatch(existingTopicName -> existingTopicName.equals(topicName));
    if (alreadyExists) {
        System.out.printf("topic already exits: %s%n", topicName);
    } else {
        //creating new topic
        System.out.printf("creating topic: %s%n", topicName);
        NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, numPartitions, (short) 1);
        admin.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic)).all().get();
    }
```

Comment: The bean creates a topic from spring config, it shouldn't take a dynamic string parameter.

Comment: I understand, any workaround for this kind of goal? @OneCricketeer

Comment: You can use a rebalance listener (or `ConsumerSeekAware`) - then use an `AdminClient` to check if the DLT exists and, if not, create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rebalance listener, or extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` (or just implement `ConsumerSeekAware`).

`public class LibraryEventsConsumer extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {`

Then, in `onPartitionsAssigned()` use an `AdminClient` to check if the DLT topic exists and, if not, create it.

Comment: Using AdminClient I solved my problem.